# Contact Form Required Fields Plugin – formEntry error

Tags: error-message

Has anyone experience with the [ContactFormRequiredFields](https://github.com/Studiosaurus/contactformrequiredfields) plugin? It works fine until the send button is pressed. It brings up an "Undefined variable: formEntry" error. When I look into the plugin I see that "formEntry" is connected to "formId". But what goes wrong?

```
        ...

        $formId = craft()->request->getPost('formId');
        $formId = craft()->security->validateData($formId);

        /**
         * Get the form entry using the ID
         */
        if ($formId)
        {
            $formEntry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($formId);
        }

        ...
```

Stack trace:

```
#0  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(693): CApplication->handleError(8, "Undefined variable: formEntry", "/var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/plugins/cont...", 
#1  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/plugins/contactformrequiredfields/ContactFormRequiredFieldsPlugin.php(48): Craft\WebApp->handleError(8, "Undefined variable: formEntry", "/var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/plugins/cont...", 48, ...)
#2  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(567): Craft\ContactFormRequiredFieldsPlugin->Craft\{closure}(Craft\ContactFormEvent)
#3  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/plugins/contactform/services/ContactFormService.php(73): CComponent->raiseEvent("onbeforesend", Craft\ContactFormEvent)
#4  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/plugins/contactform/controllers/ContactFormController.php(139): Craft\ContactFormService->onBeforeSend(Craft\ContactFormEvent)
#5  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\ContactFormController->actionSendMessage()
#6  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("p" => "anmeldung_index"))
#7  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#8  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array())
#9  /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("sendMessage")
#10 /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(836): CWebApplication->runController("contactForm/sendMessage")
#11 /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(287): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/public/index.php(19): require_once("/var/www/vhosts/tonartmusikschule.at/httpdocs/craft/app/index.ph...")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with a "Contact Form Required Fields" plugin and I'm not seeing it on https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/. Is it something you've custom written?

Comment: It is by Stephen Bowling who wrote a handy instruction for dynamic contact form code with the contactform plugin. http://stephenbowling.com/blog/2016/05/13/native-email-forms-in-craft-cms. 
The plugin: https://github.com/Studiosaurus/contactformrequiredfields

Comment: Can you enable devMode and share the stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Stack trace is now added.

Comment: Guessing you're just missing this part from the [docs](https://github.com/Studiosaurus/contactformrequiredfields#using-contact-form-required-fields)?  "The entry’s id must be included in the posted variables as formId and hashed."

Comment: @BradBell: How do I hash an Id? I tried it with {{ formId|hash }} but that wasn't the solution. I am a bit clueless here, how to use the formId so the plugin can read it.

Comment: Have you tried it without hashing it? I'm not seeing anywhere in their controller where they're checking for a hashed id, so maybe a docs error.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin expects the the ID of the entry you are using to build the form fields to be submitted along with the form so it is available as a request variable.

You should include the ID of the entry you are using to build the form’s fields when you are submitting to the `contactForm/sendMessage` controller. For example:

```
{% set form = craft.entries({
    section: 'forms',
    slug: 'contact-form',
}).first() %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
    <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="{{ form.id|hash }}" />
    ...
    {# Loop through the form fields here #}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The code above assumes you have a section with the handle *forms* and the slug of the entry you want is *contact-form*.

If you want a more robust solution that provides the form builder and validation out of the box, you might consider checking out [Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform) from Solspace.